# HorizontalTextAlignment Element in a Maui xaml file, does not change the Alignment of the text

Tags: xaml, text-alignment, maui

I am currently working on a UI for an application and I want to align the following label Text automatically horizontally, so I wanted to test, how I can align text normally.
The [Label Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label) of Maui state, that I have to do it with the HorizontalTextAlignment Element. I tried it several times and it worked, but here it won't:

```
    <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Black">
        <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type models:MessageModel}">
                <models:MessageModel Message="Hallo" Created="01.01.2001 00:00:00"/>
                <models:MessageModel Message="Hey na!" Created="01.01.2001 00:00:00"/>
            </x:Array>
        </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MessageModel">
                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Created}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

The Output is the following (And yeah I could use one Label, but I wanted to try both ways):[image: Output]
Edit: adding the following Element HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" at the label + a Background Color:
[image: Edit Pic Output]
Edit2:
[image: Edit2]

Comment: `HorizontalTextAlignment` aligns the text within the `Label`, which only matters if the `Label` is larger than the text that it contains.  By default the `Label` will only be sized large enough to fit the text unless you specify some other size constraint.  Try setting the `BackgroundColor` of the `Label` so you can visualize its actual size

Comment: @Jason I tried this too, with the HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" element and this does not work too.

Comment: again, that will tell it to fill its container, which will only do what you want if the container element is bigger than the label.  Your CV appears to be contained in a Grid, so the size of the Grid cell it's contained in will be the overall size constraint

Comment: @Jason <Grid RowDefinitions="50,12*,30" ColumnDefinitions="1*"> 
We are talking about the second element, which is the CollectionView. Is this somehow limited or what, because obviously the background color of the Collection View Container fills the entire space. I edited the post so you can see the full grid!

Comment: try putting the Label in a StackLayout

Comment: @Jason Yeah it works now, but is there no other way, using the CollectionView?

Comment: What do you mean by "using the CollectionView"? You still have CollectionView, right? Jason is saying the ItemTemplate becomes `<StackLayout ...> <Label .../> </StackLayout>`. That is a simple way to ensure the item fills the CollectionView's width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix it by handle Loaded event on page.

```
Loaded += LoginPage_Loaded;
```

In loaded hanlder add line, which change align (by defalut it start or end):

```
private void LoginPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
}
```